# Contour from 2D image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering if it's possible to plot a contour (level curves) graphic from a 2D image in Python. More specific, I'm wondering how could I read an image data (the set of the grayscale pixels, for example), and use it for the z input
I'm reading some articles about the matplotlib but I couldn't find an example which the input is an image.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please? A general answer to your question would be: *yes* - but I doubt that is what you are looking for. Can you elaborate on what you tried and how that didn't work?

Comment: Did you see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html - it  is the top hit when googling "matplotlib contour plot". It seems to show how to do exactly what you are asking. Try it - show what happened, and if it isn't what you had in mind ask a more directed question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [`contour` from matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour).

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Sample data
row = np.linspace(-2,2,20)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(row,row)
Z    = np.exp(-((X-1.5)**2+(Y+1)**2))
Z   += np.exp(-((X)**2+(Y)**2))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(Z,interpolation='none',origin='lower')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
print X,Y
```

[image]

You can also fill them in with `contourf` instead

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me how did you generated the last image? It seems to me that you used the lines color to fill the plot. In the _matplotlib_ examples, I couldn't find one like yours (very good example) about _contourf_, if my previous though was right. Thanks.

Comment: @user2666270 Take the example code I have and change `contour` to `contourf`. Glad they helped!